# Android service taking photos in background OnUiThread

Tags: android, service, android-runonuithread

I have service in which I want to take pictures of the user.
I have a timer task

```
     myTimer = new Timer();
     myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TimerMethod();
        }

    }, 0, 3000);
```

And the timer method

private void TimerMethod() {

```
    if (na != null)
        zzz.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
}

private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        takePhoto(getApplicationContext(), 1);
    }
};
```

My problem is that if i runOnUiThread the app is running slower.

How can I run in other thread that will not influence the user experience?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your TimerTask is running in main thread,this will make app runnning slower.You need a new thread to run method TimerMethod,just like this:

```
  myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {   
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    TimerMethod();
                }
            }).start();
       }

   }, 0, 3000);
```

Comment: Hello, so i should skip   zzz.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick); and make something like this?    takePhoto(getApplicationContext(), 1); inste run and remove timerMethod ?

Comment: The only principle is that you should run time-consuming method in a new thread,not in main thread.Methods in service such as onCreate(),onStartCommand() are all run in main thread.